# Organisation of a complex gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently writing a series of blogs about an ideal CI/CD Pipelines for Kubernetes deployments with different Pipeline DSLs, until now I wrote one for [Github Actions](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/05/ideal-ci-cd-pipeline-for-your-kubernetes-deployments/) and one for [Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/26/azure-devops-pipelines-for-an-ideal-ci-cd-for-your-kubertnetes-deployments/).

Now I am in the process of planing one for Gitlab, I have several use cases to fulfil as you can see [here](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/05/ideal-ci-cd-pipeline-for-your-kubernetes-deployments/#github-actions-workflows) and [here](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/26/azure-devops-pipelines-for-an-ideal-ci-cd-for-your-kubertnetes-deployments/#azure-devops-pipelines).

Now the luxury that I had with Github Action (as you can see [here](https://github.com/mehmetsalgar/credit-score/tree/master/.github/workflows)) and Azure DevOps Pipelines (as you can see [here](https://github.com/mehmetsalgar/fraud-prevention/tree/master/azure)) they have a distinct entry points for every Use Case (separate 'yml' files for Pipeline configurations reacting to different triggers (pushes, merge request creations / terminations, etc), branches, etc).

I have big conceptional problem to put my 10 Use Cases under one '.gitlab-ci.yml'.

So far best I can come up with it for Service A (there would be several Services, like Service B, C, D, etc) (please ignore the fact that pipeline does not look logical, am trying to display my dilemma, my actual logic would not look like this)

```
variables:
  CHART_NAME: "Service-A"
  USE_CASE_1: "false"
  USE_CASE_2: "false"
  USE_CASE_3: "false"
  USE_CASE_4: "false"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "development"
      variables:
        USE_CASE_1: "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature/
      variables:
        USE_CASE_2: "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release/
      variables:
        USE_CASE_3: "true"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      variables:
        USE_CASE_4: "true"

use-case-1-job-gradle:
  stage: build
  variables:
    BRANCH_NAME: "development"
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_1 == "true"

use-case-1-job-helm-package:
  stage: build
  variables:
    CHART_VERSION: "1.1.1-beta"
  needs:
    - use-case-1-job-gradle
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - build/helm/charts/*.tgz
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_1 == "true"

use-case-1-job-helm-push:
  stage: build
  variable:
    HELM_REPOSITORY_URL: oci://url1 
  needs:
    - job: use-case-1-helm-package
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_1 == "true"

use-case-2-job-gradle:
  stage: build
  variables:
    BRANCH_NAME: "feature/abc"
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_2 == "true"

use-case-2-job-helm-package:
  stage: build
  variables:
    CHART_VERSION: "1.1.1-feature-xxx"
  needs:
    - use-case-2-job-gradle
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - build/helm/charts/*.tgz
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_2 == "true"

use-case-2-job-helm-push:
  stage: build
  variable:
    HELM_REPOSITORY_URL: oci://url2
  needs:
    - job: use-case-2-helm-package
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_2 == "true"

use-case-3-job-helm-package:
  stage: build
  variables:
    CHART_VERSION: "1.1.1-feature-xxx"
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - build/helm/charts/*.tgz
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_3 == "true"

use-case-3-job-helm-push:
  stage: build
  variable:
    HELM_REPOSITORY_URL: oci://url2
  needs:
    - job: use-case-3-helm-package
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - |
       doSomething
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_3 == "true"
```

which to say the least, does not look good and I am not sure it is maintainable on the long run.

This brings me to my second dilemma, as I said before, I will have several Services and it make sense to reuse the code for Gradle Build, Helm Packaging, Helm Push etc, instead of copy pasting to different GiT Repositories. For this I create a central GiT Repository that include such central components, in 'ci-cd-gitlab-pipelines' project, I would have for ex for Helm Push the following...

```
helm-push:
  stage: deploy
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:3.11.2
  script:
    - |
      echo $HELM_PASSWORD | helm registry login $HELM_URL -u $HELM_USER --password-stdin
      helm push build/helm/charts/$CHART_NAME-$CHART_VERSION.tgz oci://$HELM_REPOSITORY_URL$HELM_PATH
```

Of course, I knew the 'include' mechanism in Gitlab so it would make sense to include the Pipeline of Gradle, Helm Package, Helm Push

```
include:
  - project: 'org.salgar.fsm.akka/ci-cd-gitlab-pipelines'
    file: '/jobs/gradle.yml'
  - project: 'org.salgar.fsm.akka/ci-cd-gitlab-pipelines'
    file: '/jobs/helm-package.yml'
  - project: 'org.salgar.fsm.akka/ci-cd-gitlab-pipelines'
    file: '/jobs/helm-push.yml'
```

Probably you see the problem, Use Case 3 does not need the Gradle, I can't find a way to include conditionally or I don't find any feasible way to control include that in 'ci-cd-gitlab-pipeline' 'helm-push.yml' other then below example.

```
helm-push:
  stage: deploy
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl:3.11.2
  script:
    - |
      echo $HELM_PASSWORD | helm registry login $HELM_URL -u $HELM_USER --password-stdin
      helm push build/helm/charts/$CHART_NAME-$CHART_VERSION.tgz
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_1 == "true"
      - $USE_CASE_2 == "true"
```

I think you would agree that that is also not nice, I read it is possible to something like '[Dynamic Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines)' but I feel creating pipelines on the run for such a basic use case is also an overkill.

Another option is to use trigger: include: mechanism...

```
use-case-3-job-helm-push:
  stage: build
  variable:
    HELM_REPOSITORY_URL: oci://url2
  needs:
    - job: use-case-3-helm-package
      artifacts: true
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'org.some/ci-cd-gitlab-pipelines'
        file: '/jobs/helm-push.yml'
  only:
    variables:
      - $USE_CASE_3 == "true"
```

which seems reasonable but I am having huge problems passing 'artifacts' (packaged helm chart) to 'helm-push', specially if there are additional downstream pipelines, I don't demonstrate here but ServiceA can trigger a Downstream Pipeline let's say in 'helm-umbrella-chart' GiT repository which also re-use the 'helm-push'.

```
trigger:
  project: 'org.some/helm-umbrella-chart'
  branch: 'development'
  strategy: depend
```

then all 'artifact' mechanism goes haywire.

I think Gitlab is not having a 'task/step' mechanism under 'job' like Github Actions [here](https://github.com/mehmetsalgar/fsm-akka-github-workflows/blob/master/.github/workflows/continuous-deployment-with-environment.yaml)

```
create-branch-helm-umbrella:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: calculate-version
  env:
    SEMVER: ${{ needs.calculate-version.outputs.semVer }}
  steps:
    - name: Create Pull Request Branch Helm Umbrella Chart
      uses: aurelien-baudet/workflow-dispatch@v2
      with:
        workflow: 'create-branch-with-reuse.yaml'
        repo: 'mehmetsalgar/fsm-akka-helm-umbrella-chart'
        ref: "${{ inputs.umbrella-chart-base-branch-name }}"
        token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
        wait-for-completion: true
        wait-for-completion-timeout: 5m
        wait-for-completion-interval: 10s
        inputs: '{"branch-name": "${{ inputs.branch-name }}-${{ inputs.repo-name }}", "base-branch-name": "${{ inputs.umbrella-chart-base-branch-name }}"}'
    - name: Deploy Helm Umbrella Chart
      uses: aurelien-baudet/workflow-dispatch@v2
      with:
        workflow: 'publish-and-prepare-environment.yaml'
        repo: 'mehmetsalgar/fsm-akka-helm-umbrella-chart'
        ref: '${{ inputs.branch-name }}-${{ inputs.repo-name }}'
        token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
        wait-for-completion: true
        wait-for-completion-timeout: 10m
        wait-for-completion-interval: 10s
        inputs: '{"branch-name": "${{ inputs.branch-name }}-${{ inputs.repo-name }}", "umbrella-chart-base-branch-name": "${{ inputs.umbrella-chart-base-branch-name }}", "source-repo": "${{ inputs.repo-name }}", "version-number": "${{ env.SEMVER }}"}'
```

or Azure DevOps pipeline here

```
- job: HelmUmbrellaChartPublish
  dependsOn:
    - CalculateBranchName
    - CalculateVersion
  displayName: "Helm Umbrella Chart Publish"
  variables:
    version: $[dependencies.CalculateVersion.outputs['calculateVersion.GitVersion.SemVer']]
    umbrella-chart-base-branch-name: ${{ parameters.umbrellaChartBaseName }}
    infrastructure-base-branch-name: ${{ parameters.infrastructureBaseBranchName }}
    build-type: ${{ parameters.buildType }}
    branch-name: $[dependencies.CalculateBranchName.outputs['cbn.myBranchName']]
    repo-name: ${{ parameters.repoName }}
    value-file: ${{ parameters.valueFile }}
  steps:
    #Create Branch with Reuse <-> fsm-akka-helm-umbrella-chart-az
    - template: dispatch.yml@fsm-akka-azure-pipelines
      parameters:
        definitionId: "19"
        sourceBranch: "$(umbrella-chart-base-branch-name)"
        inputs: '"branchName": "$(build-type)/$(branch-name)-$(repo-name)"'
    #Publish and Prepare Environment <-> fsm-akka-helm-umbrella-chart-az
    - template: dispatch.yml@fsm-akka-azure-pipelines
      parameters:
        definitionId: "14"
        sourceBranch: "$(umbrella-chart-base-branch-name)"
        inputs: '"branchName": "$(build-type)/$(branch-name)", "repoName": "$(repo-name)", "serviceVersion": "$(version)", "umbrellaChartBaseName": "$(umbrella-chart-base-branch-name)"'
    #Build Infrastructure for Environment <-> fsm-akka-helm-infrastructure-chart-az
    - template: dispatch.yml@fsm-akka-azure-pipelines
      parameters:
        definitionId: "17"
        sourceBranch: "$(infrastructure-base-branch-name)"
        inputs: '"branchName": "$(build-type)/$(branch-name)-$(repo-name)", "valueFile": "$(value-file)"'
    #Build Service Environment - fsm-akka-4eyes-argocd
    - template: dispatch.yml@fsm-akka-azure-pipelines
      parameters:
        definitionId: "21"
        sourceBranch: "master"
        inputs: '"branchName": "$(build-type)/$(branch-name)-$(repo-name)"'
```

make the passing the artifacts between the the jobs big hustle.

So I can't be only the person who has such use cases, how are you dealing with this sort of problems?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional includes are available in Gitlab CI:

```yaml
include:
- local: /.ci-templates/myfile.yaml
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```